# SAPUI5 SmartFilterBar FilterType overview

Tags: javascript, sapui5

SAPUI5 provides a `SmartFilterBar` control (package: `sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar`), this control works with metadata provided by the oData service.

According to the documentation there must be something like:
* `sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.ControlConfiguration.FILTERTYPE`

But I can't find anything like that.

My problem, default behaviour of the search fields is "equal" but I need "contains".
Example for ControlConfiguration:

```
new sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.ControlConfiguration({
    key : "Name", // string
    groupId : "_BASIC", // string
    visible : true, // boolean
    controlType : "auto", // string
    filterType : "auto", // string
    index : 1, // any
}),
```

Questions:
1. Where to find the available values for "controlType"
2. Where to find the available values for "filterType"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer:

> My problem, default behaviour of the search fields is "equal" but I need "contains".

This is unfortunately not supported in the current versions of UI5. Maybe such an option can be provided in the future, but doesn't exist right now.
"Equal" is the default, since it works for all types; "contains" only works for "Edm.String" types.

You can try to work around this by creating a Custom field and/or adding the filter with "contains" manually to the filter array result of the SmartFilterBar control.

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty self-explained as following:

```
sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.ControlConfiguration.FILTERTYPE = {
    auto: "auto",
    single: "single",
    multiple: "multiple",
    interval: "interval"
};

sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.ControlConfiguration.CONTROLTYPE = {
    auto: "auto",
    input: "input",
    dropDownList: "dropDownList",
    date: "date"
};
```

Check the complete source code at [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/comp/smartfilterbar/ControlConfiguration-dbg.js).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom data to SmartFilterBar. So this is at SmartFilterBar.

```
<mvc:View controllerName="cis.mm.controller.List" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"  xmlns:sfb="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar" xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">

<sfb:SmartFilterBar id="listFilterBar" app:useContainsAsDefaultFilter="true">
```